# Как сделать подсветку для формы

Tags: css

Например, как на страницах в твитере при регистрации ?

[image: example]

Comment: ну так посмотрите в html на твиттере, он же открыт.

Comment: Так это подсветка от браузера Chrome/Safari , это `outline` , более красивый эффект с тенью достигается за счет jQuery или подобных библиотек.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/DdkPW/7/

Comment: ох как я мог забыть про `:focus` и `box-shadow` , спасибо что напомнили )

Comment: Heidel, спасибо за помощь. Плюсануть к сожалению не могу.

Comment: только учтите, что в IE<9 это работать не будет.

Answer (score 1):

стилизировать бордер,а лучше использовать box-shadow